# export data from datagridview to excel formats

Tags: c#, excel, gridview

When I export grid view data to export to the Excel file, I get error null value. Please help me correct my codes.

```
object mis = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
app.Visible = false;
worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;
worksheet.Name = "Export";
for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
{
    worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
}
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
    }
}

SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.Filter = "Excel Document(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
sfd.FileName = "Export";
if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    workbook.SaveAs(sfd.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
}
app.Quit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var app = new Application();
_Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
app.Visible = true;
_Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet) workbook.Sheets["Sayfa1"];
worksheet.Name = "Export";
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
List < DataGridViewColumn > listVisible = new List < DataGridViewColumn > ();
foreach(DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns) {
    if (col.Visible)
        listVisible.Add(col);
}
for (int i = 0; i < listVisible.Count; i++) {
    worksheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = listVisible[i].HeaderText;
}
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < listVisible.Count; j++) {
        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[listVisible[j].Name].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Application = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application;

 var app = new Application();
 _Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
 app.Visible = false;
 _Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet) workbook.Sheets["Sayfa1"];
 worksheet.Name = "Export";
 for (var i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
 for (var i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
 for (var j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;

 var sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
 sfd.Filter = "Excel Document(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
 sfd.FileName = "Export";
 if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        workbook.SaveAs(sfd.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
 app.Quit();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply ,i have some hidden columns ,that visible property equal to no. i want , dont export to excel this columns ,what did i do?

Comment: hi ,guys , is any way that dont export columns to the excel when , visiblity is flase???

Comment: Still don't get it? Do you want to export hidden columuns Mohsen?

Comment: hi umut,your codes work fro me but ,i have problem ,that is i dont want export hidden columuns, tanks

Comment: Hidden columuns in DataGrid?

Comment: Yes i do not want export hidden columuns in datagrid to the excel

Comment: tanks for your reply bro just one problem was in output that i put picture link , sn field a number with 24 length but when export similar to picture http://uupload.ir/files/75o_1111111.png

Comment: Click cell in Excel. Then Click Home>Number>Number field in combobox.

Comment: yes bro ,i know this solution but i want when export to excel very thing be ready  and all things make from program

Comment: Get that value to string.

Comment: umut can you get new solution?

Comment: What is your email? Think you have to send your project to me. Because sometimes i dont get anything.

Comment: my email address is mtzstar@gmail.com please sent blank mail for my project bro